# IMAP criteria with multiple ORs

Tags: imap, gmail-imap

I am using gmail's IMAP API to search for mails.

I use the 'OR' criteria to search for different keywords. This works well if I go one level  only, i.e. something like

```
'UID SEARCH OR (FROM "somebody@email.com") (TO "somebody@email.com")'
```

however, it does not work when I try a longer expression like

criteria OR criteria OR criteria or criteria

which translates to (as far as I understand the syntax)

```
'UID SEARCH OR ( OR (FROM "somebodyelse@email.com") (TO "somebodyelse@email.com")) ( OR (FROM "somebody@email.com") (TO "somebody@email.com"))'
```

to make it clear I basically want all messages that are either sent from or sent to ANY of a given list of emails

The error I get from the libray is

```
[ 'A34', 'BAD', 'Could', 'not', 'parse', 'command' ]
```

any suggestions?

Comment: Try without spaces between ( and OR

Comment: Did you ever get this to work?

Comment: @kkurian not yet, I worked around it by calling for each statement separately and then concatenating the lists. I am using a node.js IMAP lib which I would have to rewrite to follow max advice. will do that later probably and post results here

Answer (score 7):

Do not use parenthesis.

IMAP uses polish notation which does not need them:

```
UID SEARCH OR OR FROM one@mail.com TO one@mail.com OR FROM two@mail.com TO two@mail.com
```

There are cases where parenthesis are needed (as IMAP AND operator can take more than 2 operands):
https://www.limilabs.com/blog/imap-search-requires-parentheses

Comment: Is the Polish notation mentioned on the rfc document?

Comment: It's not mentioned explicitly, rather entire SEARCH grammar is defined on page 89 (RFC is here: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3501#page-89). There is also no explicitly defined "AND" operator, which makes parenthesis required for some queries. I described that in the blog post in detail.

Answer (score 4):

So if you have N expressions that you want to "OR" together, you would prefix those N expressions by N-1 "OR"s.

In Perl, for example, that would be:

```
$search = join " ", ("OR") x (@exprs - 1), @exprs;
```

Answer (score 1):

Just to clarify Pawel's answer (posting since I lack the points to comment), as I didn't quite pick up the nuance:

OR is a prefix operator and can only take **two** operands (not more).  So this translates into:

```
UID SEARCH OR FROM "somebodyelse@email.com" TO "somebodyelse@email.com"
```

If you have more than two, you need to add an OR:
e.g., 3 operands

```
UID SEARCH OR OR FROM "somebodyelse@email.com" TO "somebodyelse@email.com" FROM "somebody@email.com"
```

e.g., 4 operands

```
UID SEARCH OR OR OR FROM "somebodyelse@email.com" TO "somebodyelse@email.com" FROM "somebody@email.com" TO "somebody@email.com"
```

In other words, for four operands either:
Pawel's answer of :

```
OR (OR x x) (OR x x)
```

or what I outlined above:

```
(OR (OR (OR x x) x) x)
```

Should work.