# Python imapclient search using multiple operands

Tags: python, search, imap, imapclient

I am using Python's `imapclient`, and I need to be able to search on multiple operands. For example, let's say that I want to see messages sent on Jan 6, 2018 or on Jan 13, 2018. I've looked at [IMAP criteria with multiple ORs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12809709/imap-criteria-with-multiple-ors) and at https://www.limilabs.com/blog/imap-search-requires-parentheses.

Using tips from that last reference, I've tried:

```
*r_data = M.search(['OR SENTON "6-Jan-2018"  SENTON "13-Jan-2018"'])
r_data = M.search('OR SENTON "6-Jan-2018"  SENTON "13-Jan-2018"')
r_data = M.search('SENTON "6-Jan-2018" OR SENTON "13-Jan-2018"')*
```

and a couple others. Each time I get:

```
*imaplib.error: UID command error: BAD ['Command Argument Error. 11']*
```

I'd really rather not have to dig into the `imapclient` code to work out how to structure this request. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: I'm not positive, but I would try OR (SENTON "X") (SENTON "Y").  Also, some servers have broken search implementations.  What server is that?

Comment: Can you please clarify whether you're using imaplib from the standard library or IMAPClient (https://pypi.python.org/pypi/IMAPClient/2.0.0)?

Comment: I'm using imapclient, not imaplib.

Comment: Menno, unfortunately the server I'm talking to is Exchange. I'll have a try with your suggestion.

Comment: >>> data = M.search('OR (SENTON "6-Jan-2018")(SENTON "13-Jan-2018")')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/danmahoney/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/imapclient/imapclient.py", line 725, in search
    return self._search(criteria, charset)
 <snip>
    raise self.error('%s command error: %s %s' % (name, typ, data))
imaplib.error: SEARCH command error: BAD ['Command Argument Error. 12']
>>>

Comment: FWIW, the concrete problem here is/was the doubled space before SENTON. IMAP does not permit extra spaces. It has to be `OR a b`, with exactly one space after OR and exactly one space between a and b.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came across the same issue. Found the solution to be (based upon [comments in the source code](https://github.com/mjs/imapclient/blob/master/imapclient/imapclient.py#L896)):

```
r_data = M.search(['OR', 'SENTON', '6-Jan-2018', 'SENTON', '13-Jan-2018'])
```

or maybe even better:

```
r_data = M.search(['OR', 'SENTON', date(2018, 1, 6), 'SENTON', date(2018, 1, 13)])
```

Also works for more complex queries like:

```
M.search(['OR', 'OR', 'FROM', 'a', 'FROM', 'b', 'FROM', 'c'])
```

Comment: Thanks for that! That's very helpful and should make my life a lot easier.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use query builder:

```
import datetime as dt
from imap_tools import AND, OR, NOT, Q, H   

# date not in the date list (NOT(date=date1 OR date=date3 OR date=date2))
q2 = NOT(OR(date=[dt.date(2019, 10, 1), dt.date(2019, 10, 10), dt.date(2019, 10, 15)]))
# "NOT ((OR OR ON 1-Oct-2019 ON 10-Oct-2019 ON 15-Oct-2019))"
```

[imap-tools](https://pypi.org/project/imap-tools/)